# read file from directory then read specific line of the same file c#

Tags: .net

my problem is that i'm reading a directory then i filter the files by name, but also in this directory there are other files with different names, what i am trying to do is enter this file with different name and read line number 6, and if this line matches with the name of the other files that have same name, save this files into and array to process them later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voted down.  This is not so much a programming question as a request to write a program for you.  @Tim was very kind to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String dir = @"C:\Temp";
String pattern = "*.txt";
var foundFiles = new List<String>();

foreach (String filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, pattern))
{
    foreach (String filePath2 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, pattern))
    {
         if (filePath != filePath2 &&
             File.ReadLines(filePath2).ElementAtOrDefault(5) == Path.GetFileName(filePath))
             foundFiles.Add(filePath);
    }
}
```

Note: totally untested and written without IDE, but maybe it's helpful anyway.

Comment: hi, i'm new in programming with c# could you explain what are you doing, thanks for your help..

Comment: Hello, you should have a look at the classes in the `System.IO` namespace. I'm using for example [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) to get a list of files in a directory. `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault` returns (here) the 6th line and `null` if there are not so many lines. The result is a `List<String>` what is similar to an array. Maybe you want to store the `filePath2` (or both) instead. If you want to compare with the file-name only(without `.txt` f.e.), you can use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)`.

Comment: ok Tim, actually i´m storing this files into a listbox, im gonna try this, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the simplest way to read a speciffic line.

```
string dir = "C:\\\\someFile.txt";
int LineNo = 1; //Pick a line
string ChosenLine = File.ReadAllLines(dir)[lineNo];
```

If you want to do it for every file in a folder then use a for or foreach.

```
void someMethod()
{
    string folderToScan = "C:\\\\someFolder\\";
    foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(folderToScan).ToList())
    {
        if(isExtention(dir,".txt"))
        {
            int LineNo = 1; //Pick a line
            string ChosenLine = File.ReadAllLines(dir)[lineNo];
        }
    }
}

bool isExtention(string f, string extention)
{
    return f != null && f.EndsWith(extention, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```